# Grabar (write) fichero de imagen PGM en formato P2 (ASCII)

Tags: python

¿Hay algún comando de python -opencv para escribir en formato PGM P2 (Ascii)?.
 Por defecto, python-opencv lo graba en binario (P5)

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar el parámetro `CV_IMWRITE_PXM_BINARY` asignandole el valor correcto. Si el valor es 1 (por defecto) el formato será binario (`P5`), si el valor es 0 será formato texto (`P2`). Puedes ver la documentación de [`cv.imwrite`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#bool%20imwrite(const%20String&%20filename,%20InputArray%20img,%20const%20vector%3Cint%3E&%20params)):

> For PPM, PGM, or PBM, it can be a binary format flag ( CV_IMWRITE_PXM_BINARY ), 0 or 1. Default value is 1.

Por lo tanto debes hacer algo así:

```
cv2.imwrite("output.pgm", img, (cv2.IMWRITE_PXM_BINARY, 0))
```

Si abrimos el fichero podemos ver como se indica que es de tipo ASCII PGM en el encabezado:

> P2
>   154 36
>   255
>   255 255 255 255 255 ...